# Date Detection with Python RegEx

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, regex, object-detection

its a practice project from "Automate the Boring stuff with Python" book. i am an intermediate level Python programmer and i tried to solve this problem with less code as possible. This code will not take any wrong date into consideration eg: 29-02-2002 will not be selected because 2002 is not a leap year and only leap years have 29th of feb. i did not add code to also detect dates with months written in words, i could do that too but i want to keep things simple for now and i also did not use pyperclip module to detect dates from copied text to clipboard because i dont want to confuse any beginner who also want to learn from watching my code.
I want master programmers to review my code and if their is another way possible to detect dates then please post your solutions. Also i would appreciate any advice and positive criticism, so i know where i am standing right now and what i need to improve. Thanks. Code is as follows:

````py
    import re


    def date_detector(text):
        date_pattern = re.compile('''
        ([12][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])             # to detect days from 1 to 31
        ([./-])                                # to detect different separations
        (1[0-2]|0?[1-9])                       # to detect number of months
        ([./-])                                # to detect different seperations
        (2?1?[0-9][0-9][0-9])                  # to detect number of years from 1000-2999 years
         ''', re.VERBOSE)

        days = []
        months = []
        years = []
        dates = []
        for date in date_pattern.findall(text):
            days.append(int(date[0]))
            months.append(int(date[2]))
            years.append(int(date[4]))

        for num in range(len(days)):

        # appending dates in a list that dont need any filtering to detect wrong dates
            if months[num] not in (2, 4, 6, 9, 11):
                dates.append([days[num], months[num], years[num]])

        # detecting those dates with months that have only 30 days
            elif days[num] < 31 and months[num] in (4, 6, 9, 11):
                dates.append([days[num], months[num], years[num]])

        # filtering leap years with Feb months that have 29 days
            elif months[num] == 2 and days[num] == 29:
                if years[num] % 4 == 0:
                    if years[num] % 100 == 0:
                        if years[num] % 400 == 0:
                            dates.append([days[num], months[num], years[num]])
                    else:
                        dates.append([days[num], months[num], years[num]])

        # appending Feb dates that have less than 29 days
            elif months[num] == 2 and days[num] < 29:
                dates.append([days[num], months[num], years[num]])

        if len(dates) > 0:
            for date in dates:
                print(date)


data = '30-06-2012, 31-12-2012, 15-02-2002, 29-02-2004, 29-02-2002, 31-02-2004, 31-06-2012'

date_detector(data)
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest some minor improvements in the regular expression:

- make sure that the same separator is used between day and month and between month and year with a backreference `(?P=sep)`,
- replace numbered capture groups with named, and make non-needed groups, if there are any, non-capturing with `?:`. Consequently, `finditer` and `groupdict` are used, and the day is obtained from the match with `int(date['day'])`, etc. This will make the code somewhat more human-readable.

More importantly, I suggest that you get rid of `days`, `months` and `years` lists altogether. These data can be stored in dictionaries in `dates` list and filtered prior to appending to `dates`.

As a consequence, you won't need a loop over `range(len(days))`.

The validation conditions can be OR'ed together without losing clarity, and I propose to make it a separate function `date_is_valid(day: int, month: int, year: int) -> bool`.

Also, the only parametre in `date_detector` can be made typed: `def date_detector(text: str):`.

To sum suggested modifications up:

````py
import re

def date_is_valid(day: int, month: int, year: int) -> bool:
    return (month not in (2, 4, 6, 9, 11)   # 31 days in month (Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec).
    or day < 31 and month in (4, 6, 9, 11)  # 30 days in month (Feb, Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov).
    or month == 2 and day == 29 and year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
                                            # February, 29th in a Gregorian leap year.
    or month == 2 and day < 29)             # February, 1st-28th.

def date_detector(text: str):
    date_pattern = re.compile('''
    (?P<day>[12][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])   # to detect days from 1 to 31
    (?P<sep>[./-])                      # to detect different separations
    (?P<month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])           # to detect number of months
    (?P=sep)                            # to detect different seperations
    (?P<year>2?1?[0-9][0-9][0-9])       # to detect number of years from 1000-2999 years
     ''', re.VERBOSE)

    dates = []
    for match in date_pattern.finditer(text):
        date = match.groupdict()                            # convert Match object to dictionary.
        del date['sep']                                     # we don't need the separator any more.
        date = {key: int(val) for key, val in date.items()} # apply int() to all items.
        
        if date_is_valid(date['day'], date['month'], date['year']):
            dates.append(date)

    if len(dates) > 0:
        for date in dates:
            print(date)

data = '30-06-2012, 31-12-2012, 15-02-2002, 29-02-2004, 29-02-2002, 31-02-2004, 31-06-2012'

date_detector(data)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a part of an exercise, but it feels like a lot of wheel reinventing where you can leverage builtin Python capabilities for date validation:

```
from datetime import date

>>> date(2020, 2, 29) # leap year date works
datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)

>>> date(2002, 2, 29) # non-leap year will raise ValueError
ValueError: day is out of range for month

>>> date(2002, 9, 31) # 31th day will raise ValueError
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

- instead of creating 3 separate lists for **years**, **months** and **days**, you can create only one list, since you always access these parts at the same index. That also simplifies the `for` loop which gives you the values directly instead of giving you an index you want to access in these lists.
- Python is a dynamic language where empty collections are evaluated to `False`, so when you want to check if a list has any items, you don't have to do it explicitly via `if len(list) > 0`, but you can do `if list:`. For purpose of printing items in list, you can take it one step further and omit the condition completely as iterating through an empty list wont print anything. Snippet before/after:

```py
# before
if len(dates) > 0:
    for date in dates:
        print(date)

# after
for date in dates:
    print(date)
```

all suggestion applied:

```py
import re
from datetime import date

def date_detector(text):
    date_pattern = re.compile('''
    ([12][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])             # to detect days from 1 to 31
    ([./-])                                # to detect different separations
    (1[0-2]|0?[1-9])                       # to detect number of months
    ([./-])                                # to detect different seperations
    (2?1?[0-9][0-9][0-9])                  # to detect number of years from 1000-2999 years
        ''', re.VERBOSE)

    # use only one list for storing all parts of match together
    parsed = []
    for match in date_pattern.findall(text):
        # year, month, day for easier passing to date()
        parsed.append([ int(match[4]), int(match[2]), int(match[0])] )

    valid = [] 
    for item in parsed:
        try:
            # pass list of [year, month, day] to date() and let it check its validity for us
            date(*item)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass # invalid date, dont do anything
        else:
            valid.append(item)

    for item in valid:
        print(item)


data = '30-06-2012, 31-12-2012, 15-02-2002, 29-02-2004, 29-02-2002, 31-02-2004, 31-06-2012'

date_detector(data)
```

- this can be simplified further by merging both `for` loops together, so you it does not iterate through the collection of data twice needlessly.